# JSF 1.2 How to build an outputlink inside a bean String attribute

Tags: jsf-1.2

I have a text on my site (`h:outputText value="#{myBean.myText}"`) which is built dynamically.

Sometimes I need to add a link inside this text.

So I'd like to add an outputLink inside myBean.myText.

Example : How to display this String ?

```
Click <h:outputLink value=\"#{myAction.goto('/views/anywhere.jspx'}">HERE</h:outputLink> to see!
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the rendered attribute of output text to choose when to render it- in the backing bean if the output should be a link, set rendered to false for `h:outputText`. Then, have another component `<h:commandLink>` with the rendered attribute set to the opposite of the outputText.

Something like

```
<h:outputText value="#{myBean.myText}" rendered="#{!myBean.isLink}"> </h:outputText>
<h:commandLink value="#{myBean.goto('/views/anywhere.jspx'}" rendered="#{myBean.isLink}" >HERE</h:outputLink> to see!
```

This way, only one component will be displayed at a time and you get the benefit of choosing how to style the links (eg use a different `styleclass` on outputtext vs commandlink).

Answer (score 0):

If you can get hold of your `ViewHandler` from Expression Language (this will depend on the framework), you can get the URL for an action calling  `getActionUrl()` method. For example, in Seam you can do:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="Click <a href='#{facesContext.application.viewHandler.getActionURL('/views/anywhere.jspx')}'>HERE</a> to see!" />
```

Alternatively you can create your own bean with a property that returns the url using the ViewHandler internally to the method:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="Click #{myBean.url} to see" />
```

In `MyBean`:

```
public String getUrl() {
    // Do your stuff, get current FacesContext and encode response
    // Of course, the link text, view id, etc. can all be dynamic
    ViewHandler handler = facesContext.getApplication().getViewHandler();
    String result = "Click <a href=\"" + handler.getActionUrl("/views/anywhere.jspx")
        + "\">HERE</a> to see!";
    return result;
}
```